# Loop through JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json

My Code:

```
$json2 = json_decode($content, true);
$thing = $json2{"reply1"}->{"tokens"};
foreach ($thing as $laa) {
  echo $laa->token;
}
```

Whenever I run this code against my JSON it returns:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /root/backup.php on line 33
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /root/backup.php
```

All I want to do is loop through the JSON and get one part which is the token for each [token]. (Starting part of JSON)

JSON:

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [reply] => success
    [item] => Array
        (
            [status] => CURRENT
            [messageURI] => 
        )

    [reply1] => Array
        (
            [tokens] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [token] => 123456

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [token] => 123456

                                )
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: try this `$json2["reply1"]["tokens"]` as your `$thing`, and on yout foreach try to use `$laa["token"]`

Comment: This question really has nothing to do with JSON. You've got a nested array and you're trying to access some part of it. That the array came from a string containing JSON is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @LLL $succy = $title .":". $hash ." [token=". $token['token'] ."]; This only outputs one token,  If I do echo $token['token'] it outputs two tokens. I need it to work with $succy.

Comment: Try this `$succy = "{$title}: {$hash} [token={$token['token']}]";`

Comment: Cause you miss the `"` at last.

Comment: @LLL Still the same. This is my full code: $tokens = $json2['reply1']['tokens'];
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
$succy = "{$title}:{$hash} [token={$token['token']}]";
}
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/output.txt', $succy, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

Comment: Do you have define `$title`, `$hadh` variable?

Comment: @LLL yes I do, it shows in output.

Comment: I think the bug isn't here, is at `file_put_contents`. You can try to dump `$succy`, if work great, you should check your file_put_contents.

Comment: @LLL I did echo $succy; and it still returned one token :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing an array. You do this with `[]`, not with `{}`.

To get at the tokens array, you need `$json2['reply1']['tokens']`.

Again, you access individual items in this array with `[]`, not `->`. Using `$laa->token;` is going to fail again.

Try the following

```
$tokens = $json2['reply1']['tokens'];

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
  echo $token['token']
}
```